# When i close my fram from addMouseListener it say that this is incompatible type so with what can i change this?

Tags: java

My code `dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING))` Dosen't work :

```
jTable1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                int select = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                int choi = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Voulez Vous vraiment choisir ce client ?");
                if(choi == 0){
                    Utile.idClient=jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(select, 0).toString();
                    dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));

                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please show your error log.

Comment: What is not working? Do you get errors? Use a debugger and check if the code is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an inner class `this` points to the inner instance. To get the outer instance use:

```
MyFrame.this
```

Comment: This assumes the class extends JFrame, which is shouldn't.

Comment: @HichemJAVA, Your class should NOT be extending JFrame because you are not changing the functionality of the frame. You should be creating a JPanel with all your components and then you add the panel to a frame. Search the web for "composition vs inheritance" to understand the difference between the two approaches. Once you start using "composition" when designing your classes this solution will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

"this" refers to the MouseListener, not the frame.

To find the active Window you can do something like:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForCompoent( e.getComponent() );
dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```